# \r\n showing up in <textarea> after pulled from database

Tags: php, textarea

The data is captured from a `<textarea>` to begin with.

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
etc
```

It is sent through this function before being stored in the DB (I'm open to better solutions, but if PDO is one of them, I don't understand it and have yet to get it to work)

```
function test_input($data) {
    global $conn;

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);

    return $data;
}
```

Which is my way of preventing injections (not my way but a way I found that has worked great until now its giving me this problem with line breaks in `<textarea>`).

I try to extract the data from the DB and display it in a `<textarea>`, and it shows `\r\n` instead of doing a line break.  It is stored in the DB with the line breaks (I do not see the `\r\n` but instead I see the data on a new line).

I've tried `nl2br()`, I've tried `html_entity_decode()`, I've tried `str_replace()` the `\r\n` to `<br>` (and then it just shows `<br>` literal instead of `\r\n`).

From the research I've found on this site, it's the stuff I'm doing to it before I store it in the DB that is causing this but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Comment: `\r\n` is a Windows line break. It has nothing to do with HTML entities. If you want something else, either sanitize the data before inserting it in the database or transform it after retrieval. It's not clear why this is a problem, since you know the data is there and even know how to replace it.

Comment: check the html string that is being added to the html textarea when you display it and then add some code to replace it with just '\r\n' in the string before you send it to the page.

Comment: @EdCottrell When you say sanitize the data before inserting it into the DB is that not what i'm doing with that function? I thought that was what I was doing.  And this is a problem because its not showing line breaks its showing \r\n and I can't get it to stop.

Comment: @Brody I have tried replacing the \r\n with all sorts of things an it just shows that up as a literal.  Such as \n, <br/>.  My problem is that I can't get it to replace with an actual line break in html (i've even converted the \r\n to <br> and then ran html_entity_decode on it and it still fails)

Comment: @DerekConlon I'm saying remove anything unwanted. You aren't removing `\r\n` now, but there's no reason you can't do so. Are you seeing literal `\r\n` in your output, not just a carriage return and new line? If so, that's because of your use of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. That's not a great way to handle user input and tends to make a mess of things. You really should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I just looked into Prepared Statements and I agree, I should be using those and they look like they will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `\r\n` in the text with `&#13;&#10;` before putting it into to the textarea and showing it to the user.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This May be help full

```
<?php 
function nl2br2($string) { 
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string); 
return $string; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html versus php and windows (carriage return and newline). Le
rning what happens
when you have a field of values in a buffer. A buffer can be coming from or going to an input/output device
What is inside the buffer may need to be substituted for a string appropriate to the device.
Pulling data from a DB line by line or from a SQL api query will require a regular expression and substitution operation repeating until all 
expressions are changed. Bullet proofing the input before it goes into the DB field is always a good idea.
I encountered a print problem that was caused by extra data (escape sequences) that caused the printers
to stop and wait for a reset sequence. No one understood why print jobs failed to print for something like
12 months. I wrote a filter and added it to the printers interface. PRoblem solved

Comment: I get the impression (from all of your answers) that you confuse StackOverflow with a forum. Instead it is meant to be a Q/A collection. Your story-heavy answers do not really fit that idea. Please focus your answers on how to specifically solve the problem described in the question. I.e. make an **A**nswer to the **Q**uestion.